# FlowLayoutPanel with no "line break"

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I am trying to use a `FlowLayoutPanel` to contain an arbitrary number of tall `UserControl`s, one beside the other. When a new control is added to the `FlowLayoutPanel`, I want it to appear to the right of the previous control, and never below.

I have set `AutoScroll` to `true` on the `FlowLayoutPanel` and have the `FlowDirection` as `LeftToRight`.

Below is an example of "correct" behavior (new item is added to the right and a vertical scrollbar appears for overflow):
[image: Correct side-by-side arrangement]

However, when I push past the end of "row", the `FlowLayoutPanel` drops the control to a "new line". The desired behavior is that a horizontal scrollbar appears and only the vertical overflow *from this single row* appears below.

This is an example of the **incorrect** behavior:

[image: Incorrect behavior]

How can I force all the objects to line up on a single row (ie. with a horizontal scrollbar)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for [FlowLayoutPanel.WrapContents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.wrapcontents%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. Set it to `false`, and that's it.